# Are EFA and/or ESEM models on the same data set with different factor solutions nested models?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, likelihood-ratio, confirmatory-factor

Are EFA and/or ESEM models on the same data set with different factor solutions nested models? If yes, how are they nested? Are EFA and/or ESEM models and more restrictive CFA models on the same data nested? If yes, can I perform likelihood ratio test to select the best factor solution? Can I also perform likelihood ratio test to compare EFA and/or ESEM solutions with more restrictive CFA models?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "different" factor solutions but an EFA is an ESEM in which the structural model is a zero matrix (all regressions among the efa factors). Therefore, an EFA is nested in many corresponding ESEMs that involve the same exploratory factors.

In principle, yes, a CFA may also be nested within an EFA. This is, because the factor rotation can also be understood as a (quite complicated) set of restrictions. But you would have to look at the constraints specifically to decide if the models are really nested. However, if they were nested, the EFA model would almost certainly win because you add so many parameters to the model (except if your CFA is very close to an exact fit). So there's not much to learn from the question *IF* the EFA model fits the data better. Rather, I'd ask, how much better in terms of approximative fit indices the EFA model is over the CFA.